# Creating JSON with nulls with scala.util.parsing.json

Tags: json, parsing, scala, null

How do I create a JSON string with a null value using `scala.util.parsing.json`?

```
scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull("{\"key\":null}").get
```

yields `Map("key" -> null)` but

```
scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(Map("key" -> null)).toString()
```

results in

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.util.parsing.json.JSONFormat$$anonfun$1.apply(Parser.scala:59)
    at scala.util.parsing.json.JSONFormat$$anonfun$1.apply(Parser.scala:55)
    at scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject$$anonfun$toString$1.apply(Parser.scala:96)
```

For me, this is a real head-scratcher.

Comment: Fair enough...though this was part of a simple script (I don't even compile it -- I just use the interpreter). Downloading jars or messing with sbt is a lot heavier than what I'd prefer, but I guess that's reality. Not a great first experience with the Scala libraries.

Comment: This is [a known issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5092), and apparently won't be fixed, since this library is being deprecated in 2.11. There's a reasonable argument for not having a JSON parser (even a good one, which `util.parsing.json` definitely isn't) in the standard library, and fortunately there are lots of really outstanding third-party JSON libraries for Scala.